# Singular or plural form of verb

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Which of two following sentences is correct?

1. Depending on whether 
   a birth or a death **occurs** , we have...
2. Depending on whether 
   a birth or a death **occur**, we have...

**Update** I changed the title.

Comment: The plurality of the verb has nothing to do with *"whether"*, but with whether the subject, *"a birth or a death"*, is singular or plural. So see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44349/does-a-x-of-y-take-a-singular-or-plural-verb).

Comment: Since "a birth or a death" is singular, one should use the singular form, right?

Comment: There is the possibility of 'occur' being used as subjunctive here, compare for example 'depending on whether he be a philosopher or a poet'; '... depending on whether he like ...'; '... depending on whether he make the All Blacks ...' [internet]. Perhaps subjunctive fanatics would demand it?

Comment: @Peter Shor _Which_ question?

Comment: The title asks one question, but the body is irrelevant to the title,  as @PeterShor stated. s/Depending on whether/If/ and change the title.

Comment: The title is incorrect/misleading.

Comment: @Edwin: you're right; that's the wrong question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is predicated (non-grammatical sense) on a false premise.

Comment: Be apprised that all “Which is correct?” questions are off-topic proofreading requests, and that changing the title does not affect this designation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's example #2 looks a *bit* unlikely, but in certain contexts it could be valid. As they say, [it all depends on the "whether"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22all%20depends%20on%20the%20weather%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) - in this case, whether the two possibilities are...

> 1 A: a birth occurs, **OR** B: a death occurs
> 2 A: a birth or death occurs, **OR** B: neither of those things happens *(**happen**??!!!)*

If OP intends the second distinction, the plural verb form in #2 is fine.

---

I wouldn't have a problem with a hotel manager saying...

> *"It all depends on whether the King or Queen **turn up** - if not, we might be able to let you have the Royal Suite tonight"*

In that context, the two possibilities referenced by ***whether*** are that *either* a senior royal arrives (and thus gets the best room in the house) or neither of them do (in which case you will get the accommodation upgrade).

Comment: ???Depending on whether a boy or a girl are born??? 'Depending on whether a boy or a girl is born' is the only non-subjunctive option. 'Depending on whether it's a boy or a girl that is born' and 'Depending on whether or not a boy or a girl is born' disambiguate.

Comment: @Edwin: I think by switching to *a boy/girl being born* you're changing the potential contexts in such a way that it's probably impossible to contemplate using the plural. But I'll edit...

Comment: 'whether A or B' always takes a verb agreeing in number with B, at least in traditional grammar. I've yet to see an authority licensing say 'It all depends on whether the King or Queen turn up'. 'Occur' here is, I'd say, a marginal usage corresponding to 'depending on whether a boy or a girl be born'. ie subjunctive, not plural indicative.

Comment: @Edwin: Call it "marginal" if you like. I'm perfectly happy with the plural verb form in OP's context *provided the intended sense is what I set out*. I'm blissfully unconcerned about any prescriptive grammar that tells me I *shouldn't* be happy with such usages, and I'm in no doubt that at least some other native speakers will agree with me.

Comment: This disagrees with tchrist's accepted answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86952/when-should-we-use-proximity-rule-in-either-or-and-neither-nor). And is strongly refuted by [these Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whether+he+or+she+like%2Cwhether+he+or+she+likes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhether%20he%20or%20she%20likes%3B%2Cc0). And I'm mildly concerned about do-it-yourself approaches to English.

Comment: @Edwin: Again, you're simply confusing the issue. tchrist's answer relates to constructions involving ***either***, and in any case he has a propensity to adopt uncompromising positions in relation to "correct" grammar, regardless of what people *actually* say.

Comment: People? Can you come up with some evidence, or are we descending into unsubstantiated opinion / hearsay?

Comment: Folks, we do have [ell.se] next doors. Drop in sometime.

Comment: @Edwin: I suppose you're going to tell me that [Jonathan Swift's usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22whether+the+King+or+Queen+of+that+country%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) doesn't count? *...asking me "whether the king or queen of that country **were** thick of hearing?"* Stop being so prescriptive.

Comment: I'd bet heavily that that's a subjunctive usage, especially given the date of writing. Check the previous thread.