# "The soundtrack, not the vocals, are good": Is this sentence correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, sentence

I was recently reading something online and found this sentence:

> The soundtrack, not the vocals, *are* good.

To me it seems that instead of *are good*, it should say *is good*, since the subject of the sentence is the soundtrack (Which is singular). However, now when I look at the sentence again with the *is*, it just doesn't seem right. (Since the *is* does not seem to match the plural *vocals*)

Which word is correct in this context? *is* or *are*?

Comment: when you use IS, it may feel somewhat wrong because phrase before **is** is a plural (Vocals). Otherwise I think **is** should be the word

Comment: @Vishwa That is exactly the reasoning that I have. So is _is_ correct?

Comment: In such a short sentence, the [proximity rule](https://www.thoughtco.com/proximity-agreement-grammar-1691697) prevails, i.e. it sounds most natural for the verb to agree with the closest noun.

Comment: @choster That is exactly what I'm looking for (You may add it as an answer and I will mark it correct). But one more question. If the subjects were switched, would this rule still apply? In other words, is the sentence "The vocals, not the soundtrack, _is_ good" correct?

Comment: I commented rather than answered as I assumed that the rule was already covered in a previous question. The the closest I have found, however, is [tchrist's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/86964/16052) in a question about either/or, which is not a straight-up duplicate. There is also [Ben Kovitz's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/135885/21) at our sister site for [English Language Learers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/). If no one else chimes in I will add an answer.

Comment: @choster It's been a while, care to chime in now?

Comment: That's an interesting "rule" that I'd never noticed in 60 years of listening. It sounds a perfect excuse, in speech, for when people slip up a bit but calling such a thing *rule* seems to me dreadful.